# Default routing for web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

When I create a new `ASP.NET Core Web Application` and choose `API` project template and run it, it routes to `http://localhost:64221/weatherforecast`. May I know where it configures the default routing to `weatherforecast` web api? In the `configure` method, I don't see any default routing to `weatherforecast`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the route is configured in launchSettings.json , you can find it in properties
[image]

and those are the attributes that you can change to get another route

```
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5002","launchUrl": "swagger",
```

Answer (score 2):

> May I know where it configures the default routing to weatherforecast web api?

In the `Configure` method of Startup class, you can find that `endpoints.MapControllers()`
method is called, which only maps controllers that are decorated with [routing attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis).

And in `WeatherForecastController`class, you would find `[Route("[controller]")]` is applied to it, like below.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
```

Besides, you can check [the source code of `MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder)` method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6ce8a879ae10e9f27798ec6e1c577092413f813d/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Builder/ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs#L26) and know how it works.